# Is it possible to filter results by a specific meta key's value?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm trying to show the total value for all orders in certain status whose payment method is "ppec-paypal".

I've tried using the AND function to filter by meta.meta_value

```
add_shortcode( 'show_total_pp', 'show_total_pp_shortcode' );

function show_total_pp_shortcode() {


global $wpdb;

$order_totalpp = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_sales_overview_order_totals', $wpdb->get_row( "

SELECT SUM(meta.meta_value) AS total_sales, COUNT(posts.ID) AS total_orders FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id

WHERE meta.meta_key = '_order_total'

AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'

AND meta.meta_value = 'ppec_paypal'

  AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-processing','wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )

" ) );

return absint( $order_totalpp->total_sales);

  echo $order_totalpp;

}
```

I have this code string working for orders based on just the status's, but when I try to filter the payment method by adding the line:
" AND meta.meta_value _payment_method = 'ppec_paypal' "
it does not work, gets a '0' value.
I'm guessing there is syntax error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

for a left join you should not use column related  to the left joined  table in where clause (this way work as an inner join)
but you should add this condition to the related  ON clause

```
SELECT SUM(meta.meta_value) AS total_sales, COUNT(posts.ID) AS total_orders 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id 
    AND  meta.meta_key = '_order_total'
        AND meta.meta_value = 'ppec_paypal'
WHERE  posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-processing','wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )
```